# How can I fix a Drupal Commons schema error?

Tags: mysql, drupal

Two questions here, second is a little more complicated than first.

1 - I have 18 'extra' tables in my Drupal Commons installation. Is it safe to just drop these tables from the database? (I can provide this list if it is helpful)

2 - I have 3 'mismatching table' error on the same site. Is it safe to just update these tables?

The specific tables with mismatch are:

- search_dataset
- search_index
- search_node_links

Specifically, the size of the varchar is different than it should be. Can I just update the SQL to fix this?

Comment: Ok! Looks like this is a non-issue... Wish that answer was easier to find, but I'm not going to worry about it right now! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice given here is 'do nothing' http://drupal.org/node/263582